# How to add sonarQube integration to azure devops using a script on azure-pipeline.yml file?

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

I took a look on https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/devops-platform-integration/azure-devops-integration/
And created my service connection.

Also  tested the following sample for a C# project. But my scan is done on a second script file.

How can I call the script that triggers the scan as part of the task to integrate the sonarQube connection?

```
# Prepare Analysis Configuration task
- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'YourSonarqubeServerEndpoint'
    scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
    projectKey: 'YourProjectKey'

# Dotnet build task
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'

# Run Code Analysis task
- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5

# Publish Quality Gate Result task
- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

Comment: You need to run the `prepare`, `analyze`, and `publish` steps in the same job as the compilation. You can create a pipeline decorator to inject the appropriate steps into the pipeline; refer to the documentation on pipeline decorators.